# android-pdf-viewer library does not working correctly in new android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, pdf-viewer

[image]
[image]
android-pdf-viewer library does not have any problem in android studio 2.3.3 but in new version has error.
only java file has error and XML files do not have any problem.

I test different versions of this library and add GradlePluginPortal() to sittings.gradle file

Comment: Can you show us error details?

Comment: what is the pdf library are you using?